# When are enable_if_t expressions evaluated?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<T::value == 1> * = nullptr>
void foo(T) {
    std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
} // #1

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<T::value != 1> * = nullptr>
void foo(T) {} // #2

class test{
  public:
    constexpr static int value = 1;

    test() {}
};


int main() {
    test p;
    foo(p);
}
```

Since `std::enable_if_t<T::value != 1>` demands my `value` to be static and `constexpr`, I assume that it is evaluated during compile time (I need confirmation). But since it's a template, it will depend on `T`, but I also  have this on our main and they are not `constexpr`:

```
int main() {
    test p;
    foo(p);
}
```

output:

```
test
```

So how are things evaluated at this point (order of initialization including functions) at this point? Since the compiler will need to decided which foo version will be created.

Comment: Good question. Never tried this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is evaluated at compile time. When you call, `foo(p)`, the compiler will do name lookup to find what `foo` and `p` are. It'll find two names for `foo`:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<T::value == 1>* = nullptr>
void foo(T);

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<T::value != 1>* = nullptr>
void foo(T);
```

It will then attempt to perform template substitution. Note that template substitution failure is not an error (sfinae). `T` is deduced as `test`, so we have to then non-type template arguments. The first has type `std::enable_if_t<T::value == 1>*`. We have to at this point evalute what `test::value` is. In order for substitution to succeed, there has to be some constant named `value` that is equal to one. If there is nothing named `value`, or if it's a type, or a member variable, or unequal to `1`, substitution will fail. In this case, there is a `static constexpr` `value` that is 1, so it succeeds.

The second overload fails template deduction, because there is no `enable_if<false>::type`.

Since there is only one viable overload, it is the best viable overload, and we pick it. All of this is done at compile time.

Note that if you had something like:

```
struct bad_test {
    int value = 1;
};

foo(bad_test{});
```

That will fail to compile with an error indicating that there is no matching function for `foo` - both of your overloads' template substitutions would fail as `T::value` would not be able to be evaluated in that context.

Comment: So in short: main is evaluated first before the functions are made?

Comment: @Carlo Brew: It depends on what you mean by "first". Function templates are not functions. They are *templates*. The compiler analyzes them first and memorizes them (as *templates*). Later, when you do `foo(p)` inside `main`, the compiler finds the appropriate template and generates the actual function `foo` from it.

Comment: @CarloBrew The word you're looking for is that the functions are *instantiated* at the point that they are called. Evaluation order is about what expressions at *runtime* happen before others.

Comment: @Barry so just a follow up question, does it really need to be `constexpr static int value = 1;` ? i've been trying if it's `int value = 1;` or `static int value = 1;` earlier and it wont let me compile. can you explain to me why does the template argument demands it to be constexpr and static?

Comment: @CarloBrew Because template instantiation happens at compile time - so everything you need to instantiate a template (in this case, knowing if `value` is 1 or not) has to be available at that time. The standard term is: it has to be a [core constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Template parameters are always compile-time entities evaluated strictly at compile time.

In your example with `foo(p)`, the template argument is deduced as `T == test`, which is done at compile time. Once it is known that `T == test`, the value of `T::value` is known as `test::value`, which exists and which is a constexpr (also known at compile time).

Comment: But from my example, it's `T`. So how did it know that i am about to pass `test p` wherein the only constexpr is the `value` member of test?

Comment: What does "about to pass" mean in this case? The compiler sees clearly that you *passed* `p`, which is an object of type `test`. At that point it deduces `T == test` and instantiates the appropriate version of `foo` from your templates. Template functions are generally *instantiated* (i.e turned into real functions) *at the point of the call*, not earlier.

Comment: Ahhh i see. So function templates generates function only if they are called?

Comment: @Carlo Brew: Yes, exactly. The actual functions are generated (instantiated) "on demand", at the point of the call, where all template arguments are known. A separate version of the function is generated for each combination of template arguments. It is possible to force template instantiation without a call, but that's a different story.